# Can't unit test a working file upload with node/express

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I am trying to unit test a node/express upload file.This is my first piece of work tying node.I could get the job done in the frontend but hen I had to test it,it went downhill... The file gets uploaded on both frontend and when unit testing but I get an error of `res.json is not a function`mostly because I change the CVS to a JSON file in writeFile.

I tried to change the unit test a fair amount of time but I think I am stuck.I've changed the file parameter the attach parameter etc...

test.js

```
var request = require("supertest");
const app = require('../routes/file');

describe('/upload file', () => {
    it('Should upload a file', (done) => {
        request(app).post('/upload',function(err,res){
            console.log('asdasdasd');
            done();
        })
         .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
         .set('Accept', 'application/json')
         .attach('file', "testdata.csv")
         .end(function(){

          });
    });
```

file.js

```
router.post('/upload',function(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    let filePath = req.file.path;
    let fileExtension = path.extname(filePath);

      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError || fileExtension !== '.csv') {
          return res.status(500).json(err);
      } else if (err || fileExtension !== '.csv') {
          return res.status(500).json(err);
      }

    CSVToJSON({
        headers: ['id', 'name', 'age', 'address', 'team'],
        noheader: true,
      }).fromFile(filePath).then(source => {
        helpers.writeFile('data',filePath,source,res);
        });
    });
});
```

helpers.js

```
writeFile(fileName,filePath,source,res){
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    fs.writeFile(`../public/files/${fileName}.json`,JSON.stringify(source),'utf-8',function (err) {
         if (err) {
           return res.json({"error" : true, "message" : err,'status':500});
         } else {
        return res.json({"error" : false, "message" : "File Uploaded Successfuly",'status':200});
         }
    });
   }
}
```

I expected a status of 200 and res.json to be defined.